# Cisco, How to do a subnetting scheme using VLSM and RIP-2?

Tags: cisco, subnet

I'm studying for my CCNA exam and I have to create a VLSM scheme using RIP-2 for the following requirements:
(this is an exercise)

1. Use the class C network 192.168.1.0 network for your point-to-point connections
2. Using the Class A network 10.0.0.0, plan for the following number of hosts in each location:
   New York: 1000
   Chicago: 500
   Los  Angeles: 1000
3. On the LAN and point-to-point connections, select subnet masks that use the smallest ranges of IP addresses possible given the above requirements.
4. In all cases, use the lowest possible subnet numbers.  Subnet zero is allowed.

My guess is the following:

New York: S0/0 192.168.1.1 /24 Fa0/0 10.1.0.1 netmask 255.255.248.0 - because we need 1000 hosts 
Chicago:  S0/0 192.168.1.2 /24 Fa0/0 10.2.0.1 netmask 255.255.252.0 (for 500 hosts) 
Los Angeles: S0/0 192.168.2.3 /24 Fa0/0 10.3.0.1 netmask 255.255.248.0 (for 1000 hosts)

Is this a good configuration? I'm reading the CCNA book but not everything is very clear, so I said to do some exercises...

Thank you!

Comment: for question 1, you using two class c networks 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.2.3 , these are on different subnets. As point to point links only contain 2 ip address, subnet zero and all 1's broadcasts, you can get 192.168.1.0/24 and subnet it down , I'll let you figure out how many point to point links you can accommodate!

Comment: I got the problem with point 1.
I will have 3 subnets 192.168.1.0\24, 192.168.1.0\25 and 192.168.1.0\26

Comment: Cisco is still using the terminology of Class-based IP? Clas A/B/C/D? Really? That's sad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer:
Set the following IP addresses to each it corresponding interface:

192.168.1.0 /30

Chicago 
office network 10.0.8.1/23  
192.168.1.5 int to LA  
192.168.1.2 int to NY

NY 
office network 10.0.0.1/22 
192.168.1.1  int to  CH 
192.168.1.10 int to  LA

LA 
office network 10.0.4.1/22 
192.168.1.6 int to CH 
192.168.1.9 int to NY

next you have to set RIP-2 on each router for the 192.168.1.0 and 10.0.0.0 network and after disable the auto-summarization on each router.

Comment: Not explicitly stated, but it's usually address-conserving to start with the largest IP blocks, then allocate ranges for smaller and smaller blocks. That way, you don't end up with holes in the IP allocation.